# Ubuntu keeps restarting after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04

I updated ubuntu from 18.04 from 16.04. On start I get grub as expected with 2 options

1. Windows boot manager.
2. grubx64efi

. I choose 'grubx64efi option expecting to get into ubuntu, but the system reboots and then lands back in grub.

I have tried starting up from USB and running boot repair. Didnt help and I keep getting the same problem.

While I doing the update I was asked something along the lines of what to d with your grub and I chose an option which says to keep the configuration as is now. Could this be causing an issue ? How do I resolve this ?

Comment: grubx64.efi refers to GRUB file only. Menu entry for Ubuntu is missing in your grub. I believe

Comment: Ok . Let me see if I can find out how to add it .

Comment: Try to chroot from live DVD , then check the log files to see what is the error cause this

Comment: a newbie here .. do you have any reference to how I can do this ?

Comment: Try boot-repair again via LiveUSB and see if it detects Ubuntu. Save the log file and try to upload or paste the content in https://paste.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

Did the following steps to solve the issue.

1. Created a LiveUSB.
2. Choose the option to Try Ubuntu without install on start up.
3. Ran [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)but I was asked to disable secure boot in BIOS which I did.
4. Disabled Secure boot and ran boot-repair again and was able to access Ubuntu